# Trying to install pycaret but receiving an error

Tags: python, pycaret

Having this error while installing pycaret through following command:

```
!pip install pycaret..
```

```
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  
  
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: legacy-install-failure
  
  Encountered error while trying to install package.
  
  numpy
  
  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for output from the failure.
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have tried the command !pip install pycaret on jupyter notebook but it continuously giving the same error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please share the entire error traceback? Please share the details of your Python version and which OS you are using as well.

Comment: Side note from experience: it's safer to install PyCaret on a new virtual environment in order to avoid issues with incompatible packages and having a rollback plan. Have you tried installing via command prompt? Have you tried pip3 instead of pip?
This error is related to numpy, not pycaret per se. Is numpy already installed? Which version?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend installing the pre-release version of pycaret (3.0.0rc4 as of writing this answer). Many of the common installation issues have been resolved there. Make sure you are installing this on a new (conda) environment.

```
pip install -U --pre pycaret
```

## Update

Now, you can simply install the released version instead of the pre-release version. This should install pycaret 3.0.0 or greater.

```
pip install pycaret
```